# Does ioredis mset() accepts options to set expiry, like set operation does?

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis, redis-cache

Here is my code:

```
const Redis = require('ioredis');
const client = new Redis();
// multi set
client.mset({'key1': 'value1'});
```

Question is does `mset` operation accept options to set `TTL` like `set` command does?

// sample for set

```
client.set(key, value, 'EX', 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

No it does not. `MSET` is used for `just` for setting multiple values for the keys. As you may can see here from the [implementation](https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/f2db379fa3f6e0c0d81350fd0f29febea95df469/src/t_string.c#L309), there is no option to set expiration for the keys. Another variation [MSETNX](https://redis.io/commands/msetnx) also does not support optional expiration.

You need to execute `EXPIRE` command for each key you set in `MSET`. Another option could be executing them in transaction or completely discarding `MSET` but use `SETEX`(or `SET` with `EX` option) for each key.

Comment: thanks for the information. I figured it out that way from documentation, It is annoying why they won't allow to set the expiry on multi key select.